# Chrome extension how to include content security policy for chrome-extension://

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have tests running for my chrome extension and I execute them from chrome-extension://extensionid/tests.html

I get content security policy errors that do not allow in-line scripts. Is there any way that I can remove these while testing? (add a meta tag that disables it for that html or some other way that won't make the extension less secure?)

I have added the following in the head of my test.html page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'sha256-jynp9uOEMlgu3tR4l2Dr3s2aDinAZ60XBJB90peqSiY=' 'sha256-15MCFd4+StoldY1/R3pkitrT0zw4gNvsPZieV/QiqRE=' 'sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=' 'sha256-PnGpdwmF8gaODbB6epAipygkpV6GFPS46JZtI9veRzU=' 'sha256-J4clsEh5/6tMX7sob7FXvQGfQUYKmTGqi2iPvj3P6n4=' https://apis.google.com/ https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'">
```

But I still get errors in the console about content security policy. The error shows still the old policy from my manifest.json.

Comment: CSP can be only tightened when specifying a meta tag, AFAIK, so you'll have to modify the global CSP in manifest.json for the duration of the test. Alternatively, if the test doesn't need to access `chrome` API, you can declare that test page as a [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval).

Comment: I updated my question with the code that I used in the meta but it does not look like it overrides the manifest.json records. Sadly, I use chrome functions in the tests so sandbox wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Actually [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) answered fist part of the question - the additional headers/ could make the resulting CSP more restrictive only.

When multuple CSPs presents, to be applyed all sources/tokens should pass unscratched via all CSPs (filtered through all policies) - this section is not normative in [CSP spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#multiple-policies), but the [test](https://csplite.com/csp/test23/) shows that Chrome and Firefox follow it. It does not matter how CSPs where delivered to the page via HTTP header, `<meta>`-tag or  even [HTTP header + meta](https://csplite.com/csp/test219/).

As you wrote `The error shows still the old policy from my manifest.json` - it menas this CSP is more restrictive in your case.

2. If you **won't to make the extension less secure** - just move `sha256-values` from meta-tag to CSP in the manifest.json. This will allow inline scripts with those hashes only, no one other script will be allowed.

Negative moment - you need to recalc hasheas after each scripts changes, but Chrome will do it for you

Comment: Thank you! That explains a lot.